# Consecutive Days if I logout my account

Tags: support

I'm logged right now in SO using my openID account .. if I logged out and then log in again using my stack exchange account will I going to lose my consecutive days or it will stay continue updating on the current value ?

Edit :

I asked the question because when I press logout I'm having this message from SO "Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser, and log you out on all devices."

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that it was a different account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the logins linked to the same account?

As in, do you have the same rep/badges when you login from either account? If so, you keep the consecutive days.

If you have two *different* profiles, then they won't be kept-- you can request a mod to account-merge.

Comment: no they are linked to the same account .. but this is the first time I try to login to SO using the stack exchange account .. however in meta  SO it shows my SO account rep and badges correctly.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi: Yep, no problem.. Your login consecutive dates will stay--the OpenID provider only matters for the duration of login, that's it.

Comment: the only thing makes me hesitate to logout is when I press logout I'm having this message from SO "Clicking Log Out will clear all local credentials in your browser, and log you out on all devices." .. are you sure that i will not lose my consecutive days ??

Comment: @Malek LOCAL credentials. This means cookies &c-basically all records of you being logged in are cleared from YOUR computer. But SE keeps a record of when you last logged in, so its not a problem

Comment: @Malek note that if you're gunning for that badge (Fanatic), you have to do more than just be logged in.. I think thr level of activity requiredhas  not been disclosed, though.

Comment: yeah actually I'm looking forward it .. and yeah I don't just make a  login I try to be daily active on the SO.

Comment: @Malek Yeah, that's great then! Note that you can click the green tick next to this answer ('accept this question') if it solved your problem. I noticed that you haven't accepted any answers on SO, either--people will tend to avoid your questions if you have a low accept rate.

Comment: My bad, looks like you HAVE accepted answers.. :/

Comment: yeah sure i will accept your answer after i try it .. don't worry :)

Comment: Thats it .. you are right .. Thank you , and don't say again that I'm not accepting any answers :)) .

Comment: @Malek no problem. About the accepted answers, i messed up due to a difference in the mobile and main site color schemes--didn't see the faint green :P

Comment: I'm just joking man :)

Comment: @Malek_Jundi: I know ;-)